# Padding inside table cell despite td{padding:0}

Tags: html, css

I'm having this quite annoying bug for a while now.. The problem is quite simple, there is this huge padding appearing on the top and bottom of a table cell when i place an object (in this case, image) in it.

What I am trying to do is place different objects in a Grid set up as table in HTML so that's why you will see all those extra cells. initial width and height of table and cells is known, I just specify col/row span of the cell in which the object will be placed based on object's width/height.

I have searched and applied many solutions like cellspacing,cellpadding = 0, padding: 0, img's display block but nothing seems to be working here.

```css
td{border:1px solid black; padding:0}
```

```html
<table style="width:600pt; height:800pt; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td rowspan="15" colspan="15" ><img style="width:298pt; height:292pt;" src="http://i.imgur.com/mrxsiZ3.jpg"/>
</td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="18" colspan="30" ></td></tr>
</table >
```

Img is placed in 8th row and 8th column of the grid but it slides quite a lot way down in the cell because of the padding. Inspecting the cell in browser will clear out the problem.

Fiddle can be found [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vrsar26/) for your convenience

Answer (score 2):

The padding is only there because your force the table to have a height of 800 pixels. If you remove the height property, the padding disappears.

```css
td{border:1px solid black; padding:0;}
```

```html
<table style="width:600pt; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="30" ></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td rowspan="15" colspan="15" ><img style="width:298pt; height:292pt;" src="http://i.imgur.com/mrxsiZ3.jpg"/>
</td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="18" colspan="30" ></td></tr>
</table >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the table to be that height, your other option is to set the height property directly on the td. This will adjust all of the other tds accordingly to add to your set table height. But the issue is that tds for a tr are always the same height. So if you set the height on multiple tds within the same tr, the height for all of the tds will be set to the largest td height.

That may have sounded confusing but basically, you can't tailor each table data uniquely to a picture if your pictures aren't the same size. You may get "that" table data to have the "padding" removed but once you add more pictures, you're going to have padding on at least one of your photos if they aren't the same size.

This solution might work for you but I would consider using a design framework. A grid system might be easier for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want the image at the top? If thats the case use vertical align.

```
<td rowspan="15" colspan="15" style="vertical-align:top">
    <img style="width:298pt; height:292pt;" src="http://i.imgur.com/mrxsiZ3.jpg"/>
</td>
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kftckrfh/)**